# unable to change date format with "/" as separator , if default system date format having "-" as date separator

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

In my local machine System short Date setting is of format "M/d/yyyy". In my C# code i can convert DateTime to "dd/MM/yyyy" or "dd-MM-yyyy" format using

```
//1
var date=string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now) //output is:05/09/2017
//2
var date=string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", DateTime.Now) //output is:05-09-2017
```

But if i change my system date settings of short date to "yyyy-MM-dd" or simply any date format having "-" as separator instead of "/" i'm unable to convert date to other formats like

```
//3
var date=string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", DateTime.Now) //output is:05-09-2017
//4
var date=string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now) //output is still :05-09-2017
```

In the above code even i have changed separator to "/" it's still giving "-" in the output.How can i output 4th one to "05/09/2017".

Comment: You can try ToString format: DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `/` character is a special formatting character for `DateTime` which says "use the specified/current locale's date separator".

If you want to force it to use `/` you have to escape the character by surrounding it with single quotes:

```
var date=string.Format("{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}", DateTime.Now)
```

[Alteratively, you can escape it with the `\` character:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#escape)

```
var date=string.Format("{0:dd\\/MM\\/yyyy}", DateTime.Now)
```

(But I find the first approach to be slightly more readable.)

Finally, you can also use double-quotes to escape it, but that's even less readable:

```
var date = string.Format("{0:dd\"/\"MM\"/\"yyyy}", DateTime.Now);
```

Alternatively (as Jon points out) you can override the culture to use one that uses `/` as a separator:

```
var date = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Or force a `CultureInfo` that uses `/` as the separator, of course.